kretprobe handler hooks show BUG: scheduling while atomic
I tried to use kretprobe to hook the umount syscall with a post handler in my kernel module.
static struct kretprobe umount_kretprobe = {
    .entry_handler  = umount_kprobe_pre_handler,
    .handler        = umount_kprobe_post_handler,
    .kp.symbol_name = "__x64_sys_umount",
    .data_size      = sizeof(struct umount_data),
    // /* Probe up to 20 instances concurrently. */
    .maxactive      = 20,
};

In the post handler (umount_kprobe_post_handler), we found that in some scenarios, when we are in the hooked post handler, the umount operation has not been synced by the OS. However, I want to ensure the umount syscall return value in the post handler, so we need to flush it first.
The flush function I used looked like this:
void flush_tasks(){
        struct task_struct *task = current;
        struct callback_head *work, *head, *next;

        for (;;) {
                do {
                        work = ACCESS_ONCE(task->task_works);
                        head = NULL; // current should not be PF_EXITING
                } while (cmpxchg(&task->task_works, work, head) != work);

                if (!work)
                        break;

                raw_spin_lock_irq(&task->pi_lock);
                raw_spin_unlock_irq(&task->pi_lock);

                head = NULL;
                do {
                        next = work->next;
                        work->next = head;
                        head = work;
                        work = next;
                } while (work);

                work = head;
                do {
                        next = work->next;
                        work->func(work);
                        work = next;
                        cond_resched();
                } while (work);
        }
}

After we called this function in umount_kprobe_post_handler, the kernel bug "BUG: scheduling while atomic" was triggered.
The call stack showed:
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024] BUG: scheduling while atomic: umount/3090/0x00000002
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024] Modules linked in:  nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_ct nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 rfkill ip_set nf_tables qrtr intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common intel_uncore_frequency_common isst_if_mbox_msr sunrpc isst_if_common nfit libnvdimm rapl raid1 dm_raid i2c_piix4 virtio_balloon raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq pktcdvd async_xor async_tx joydev fuse loop dm_multipath nfnetlink zram xfs crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 sha256_ssse3 virtio_scsi sha1_ssse3 virtio_net net_failover bochs drm_vram_helper drm_ttm_helper ttm failover qemu_fw_cfg serio_raw ata_generic pata_acpi scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua virtio_console
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024] CPU: 1 PID: 3090 Comm: umount Tainted: G           OE     -------  ---  6.8.0-0.rc6.49.fc40.x86_64 #1
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS Virtualization-2.5.1-11303-200428-0-gfff70e7 04/01/2014
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024] Call Trace:
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  <TASK>
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  dump_stack_lvl+0x4d/0x70
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  __schedule_bug+0x56/0x70
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  __schedule+0x10a7/0x1530
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  ? mod_delayed_work_on+0x66/0xb0
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  ? wb_queue_work+0x8e/0x100
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  schedule+0x32/0xd0
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  wb_wait_for_completion+0x89/0xc0
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  __writeback_inodes_sb_nr+0xa4/0xd0
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  sync_filesystem+0x31/0xa0
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  generic_shutdown_super+0x26/0x110
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  kill_block_super+0x1a/0x40
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  ext4_kill_sb+0x22/0x40
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  deactivate_locked_super+0x30/0xb0
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  cleanup_mnt+0xba/0x150
[Mon Jul  1 06:23:07 2024]  flush_tasks+0x7c/0xa0 [my_module]

I assume that the root cause of this bug is that kretprobe's handlers were designed to be atomic, so we cannot trigger scheduling in the pre/post handlers of its hook. Am I correct?
Can anyone suggest a workaround for this? I want to hook the umount syscall with a post handler and need to check that the umount has been completed by the OS for sure.
